# Sending an email in the background

Tags: android

I've been working on an app that would send 2 emails, one button would send an email with the email client open ,the other would be sent in the background.
I tried using Gmail Sender to send the app in the background.  The button to send with the app works but the app stops working when I press the other one & I get the following error message.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: queens.feedback, PID: 2361
                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                   at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:974)
                                                                   at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:646)
                                                                   at queens.feedback.Utils.isNetworkAvailable(Utils.java:29)
                                                                   at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail.send(BackgroundMail.java:242)
                                                                   at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$Builder.send(BackgroundMail.java:443)
                                                                   at queens.feedback.Happy.onClick(Happy.java:41)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please could you let me know where I'm going wrong? (****** are the email address & password.)

```
public class Happy extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    final Context context = this;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_happy);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                Intent h = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                h.setType("message/rfc822");
                h.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"***************"});
                h.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I'm happy");
                h.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(h, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(Happy.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button01:
                BackgroundMail.newBuilder(this)
                        .withUsername("************")
                        .withPassword("*********")
                        .withMailto("**************")
                        .withSubject("this is the subject")
                        .withBody("this is the body")
                        .withOnSuccessCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnSuccessCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                //do some magic
                            }
                        })
                        .withOnFailCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnFailCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFail() {
                                //do some magic
                            }
                        })
                        .send();

                //BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(context);
               // bm.setGmailUserName("***************");
                //bm.setGmailPassword("***********");
                //bm.setMailTo("*************");
                //bm.setFormSubject("I'm Happy");
                //bm.setFormBody("No comment");
                //bm.send();
                break;
        }
        ;
```

I noticed that a lot of the methods in this class aren't being used I think this might be the cause of the problem but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

```
package com.creativityapps.gmailbackgroundlibrary;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.ArrayRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.creativityapps.gmailbackgroundlibrary.util.GmailSender;
import com.creativityapps.gmailbackgroundlibrary.util.Utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class BackgroundMail {
    String TAG = "BackgroundMail";
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String mailto;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private String sendingMessage;
    private String sendingMessageSuccess;
    private String sendingMessageError;
    private boolean processVisibility = true;
    private ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback;
    private OnFailCallback onFailCallback;

    public interface OnSuccessCallback {
        void onSuccess();
    }

    public interface OnFailCallback {
        void onFail();
    }

    public BackgroundMail(Fragment fragment) {
        this(fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    public BackgroundMail(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.sendingMessage = context.getString(R.string.msg_sending_email);
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = context.getString(R.string.msg_email_sent_successfully);
        this.sendingMessageError=context.getString(R.string.msg_error_sending_email);
    }

    private BackgroundMail(Builder builder) {
        mContext = builder.context;
        attachments = builder.attachments;
        username = builder.username;
        password = builder.password;
        mailto = builder.mailto;
        subject = builder.subject;
        body = builder.body;
        setSendingMessage(builder.sendingMessage);
        setSendingMessageSuccess(builder.sendingMessageSuccess);
        setSendingMessageError(builder.sendingMessageError);
        processVisibility = builder.processVisibility;
        setOnSuccessCallback(builder.onSuccessCallback);
        setOnFailCallback(builder.onFailCallback);
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder(Context context) {
        return new Builder(context);
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder(Fragment fragment) {
        return new Builder(fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void setGmailUserName(@NonNull String string) {
        this.username = string;
    }

    public void setGmailUserName(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.username = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getGmailUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setGmailPassword(@NonNull String string) {
        this.password = string;
    }

    public void setGmailPassword(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.password = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getGmailPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void showVisibleProgress(boolean state) {
        this.processVisibility = state;
    }

    public boolean isProgressVisible() {
        return processVisibility;
    }

    public void setMailTo(@NonNull String string) {
        this.mailto = string;
    }

    public void setMailTo(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.mailto = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getMailTo() {
        return mailto;
    }

    public void setFormSubject(@NonNull String string) {
        this.subject = string;
    }

    public void setFormSubject(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.subject = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getFormSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setFormBody(@NonNull String string) {
        this.body = string;
    }

    public void setFormBody(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.body = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getFormBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setSendingMessage(@NonNull String string) {
        this.sendingMessage = string;
    }

    public void setSendingMessage(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.sendingMessage = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getSendingMessage() {
        return sendingMessage;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageSuccess(@Nullable String string) {
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = string;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageSuccess(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getSendingMessageSuccess() {
        return sendingMessageSuccess;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageError(@Nullable String string) {
        this.sendingMessageError = string;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageError(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.sendingMessageError = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getSeningMessageError() {
        return sendingMessageError;
    }

    public void addAttachment(@NonNull String attachment) {
        this.attachments.add(attachment);
    }

    public void addAttachment(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.attachments.add(mContext.getResources().getString(strRes));
    }

    public void addAttachments(@NonNull List<String> attachments) {
        this.attachments.addAll(attachments);
    }

    public void addAttachments(String...attachments) {
        this.attachments.addAll(Arrays.asList(attachments));
    }

    @NonNull
    public List<String> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void setOnSuccessCallback(OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback) {
        this.onSuccessCallback = onSuccessCallback;
    }

    public void setOnFailCallback(OnFailCallback onFailCallback) {
        this.onFailCallback = onFailCallback;
    }


    public void send() {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You didn't set a Gmail username");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You didn't set a Gmail password");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mailto)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You didn't set a Gmail recipient");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You didn't set a body");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(subject)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You didn't set a subject");
        }
        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "you need internet connection to send the email");
        }
        new SendEmailTask().execute();
    }

    public class SendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (processVisibility) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                progressDialog.setMessage(sendingMessage);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                GmailSender sender = new GmailSender(username, password);
                if (!attachments.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
                        if (!attachments.get(i).isEmpty()) {
                            sender.addAttachment(attachments.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
                sender.sendMail(subject, body, username, mailto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (processVisibility) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (result) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sendingMessageSuccess)) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, sendingMessageSuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (onSuccessCallback != null) {
                        onSuccessCallback.onSuccess();
                    }
                }else {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sendingMessageError)) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, sendingMessageError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (onFailCallback != null) {
                        onFailCallback.onFail();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private Context context;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String mailto;
        private String subject;
        private String body;
        private ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
        private String sendingMessage;
        private String sendingMessageSuccess;
        private String sendingMessageError;
        private boolean processVisibility;
        private OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback;
        private OnFailCallback onFailCallback;

        private Builder(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.sendingMessage = context.getString(R.string.msg_sending_email);
            this.sendingMessageSuccess = context.getString(R.string.msg_email_sent_successfully);
            this.sendingMessageError=context.getString(R.string.msg_error_sending_email);
        }

        public Builder withUsername(@NonNull String username) {
            this.username = username;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withUsername(@StringRes int usernameRes) {
            this.username = context.getResources().getString(usernameRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPassword(@NonNull String password) {
            this.password = password;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPassword(@StringRes int passwordRes) {
            this.password = context.getResources().getString(passwordRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMailto(@NonNull String mailto) {
            this.mailto = mailto;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMailto(@StringRes int mailtoRes) {
            this.mailto = context.getResources().getString(mailtoRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSubject(@NonNull String subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSubject(@StringRes int subjectRes) {
            this.subject = context.getResources().getString(subjectRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withBody(@NonNull String body) {
            this.body = body;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withBody(@StringRes int bodyRes) {
            this.body = context.getResources().getString(bodyRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withAttachments(@NonNull ArrayList<String> attachments) {
            this.attachments.addAll(attachments);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withAttachments(String...attachments) {
            this.attachments.addAll(Arrays.asList(attachments));
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withAttachments(@ArrayRes int attachmentsRes) {
            this.attachments.addAll(Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(attachmentsRes)));
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSendingMessage(@NonNull String sendingMessage) {
            this.sendingMessage = sendingMessage;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSendingMessage(@StringRes int sendingMessageRes) {
            this.sendingMessage = context.getResources().getString(sendingMessageRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSendingMessageSuccess(@Nullable String sendingMessageSuccess) {
            this.sendingMessageSuccess = sendingMessageSuccess;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSendingMessageSuccess(@StringRes int sendingMessageSuccessRes) {
            this.sendingMessageSuccess = context.getResources().getString(sendingMessageSuccessRes);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSendingMessageError(@Nullable String sendingMessageError) {
            this.sendingMessageError = sendingMessageError;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSendingMessageError(@StringRes int sendingMessageError) {
            this.sendingMessageError = context.getResources().getString(sendingMessageError);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withProcessVisibility(boolean processVisibility) {
            this.processVisibility = processVisibility;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOnSuccessCallback(OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback) {
            this.onSuccessCallback = onSuccessCallback;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOnFailCallback(OnFailCallback onFailCallback) {
            this.onFailCallback = onFailCallback;
            return this;
        }

        public BackgroundMail build() {
            return new BackgroundMail(this);
        }

        public BackgroundMail send() {
            BackgroundMail backgroundMail = build();
            backgroundMail.send();
            return backgroundMail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary?

Comment: I had a background mail class

Comment: Did simple clicking working? Try add Log.d("APP", "Button clicked"); to make sure it.

Comment: Hi clicking worked but it didn't do anything.  Where do I add  Log.d("APP", "Button clicked");

Comment: I managed to get the 1st button working however I get a message that the app has stopped working when I press the second one.

Comment: I get this error message 06-30 08:19:46.390 2361-2361/queens.feedback E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: queens.feedback, PID: 2361
                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)

Comment: I would say the main exception in this log is "Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" so check your permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: `ConnectivityService: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.`

Comment: Thanks but ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is added as one of the permissions.

Comment: I also tried cleaning & rebuilding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

Add this to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: However it is red & says element uses permission isn't allowed here.  Along with Android version code. When I checked the debug/android manifest.

Comment: Had the permissions in the wrong place in the Android Manifest.  I Checked the backgroundmailLibrary again & was able to find a demo which helped me to get ti working.